# i get this alert in my app , only in android.Created with phonegap

Tags: android, cordova, pushwoosh

I need help to find where is this alert on my app with **phonegap and pooshwoosh** notification. I get this alert only on android.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- config.xml reference: https://build.phonegap.com/docs/config-xml -->
<widget xmlns     = "http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"
        xmlns:gap = "http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0"
        id        = "........."
        version   = "1.0.1">

    <name>....</name>

    <description>
       .... 
    </description>

    <author .....
    </author>

    <!--
        Enable individual API permissions here.
        The "device" permission is required for the 'deviceready' event.
    -->
    <feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/device" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device" version="0.2.8" />


    <!--
        If you do not want any permissions to be added to your app, add the
        following tag to your config.xml; you will still have the INTERNET
        permission on your app, which PhoneGap requires.
    -->
    <preference name="permissions"                value="none"/>

    <!-- Customize your app and platform with the preference element. -->
    <!-- <preference name="phonegap-version"      value="3.4.0" /> -->      <!-- all: current version of PhoneGap -->
    <preference name="orientation"                value="default" />        <!-- all: default means both landscape and portrait are enabled -->
    <preference name="target-device"              value="universal" />      <!-- all: possible values handset, tablet, or universal -->
    <preference name="fullscreen"                 value="true" />           <!-- all: hides the status bar at the top of the screen -->
    <preference name="webviewbounce"              value="true" />           <!-- ios: control whether the screen 'bounces' when scrolled beyond the top -->
    <preference name="prerendered-icon"           value="true" />           <!-- ios: if icon is prerendered, iOS will not apply it's gloss to the app's icon on the user's home screen -->
    <preference name="stay-in-webview"            value="false" />          <!-- ios: external links should open in the default browser, 'true' would use the webview the app lives in -->
   <!-- <preference name="ios-statusbarstyle"         value="black-opaque" />    ios: black-translucent will appear black because the PhoneGap webview doesn't go beneath the status bar -->
    <preference name="detect-data-types"          value="true" />           <!-- ios: controls whether data types (such as phone no. and dates) are automatically turned into links by the system -->
    <preference name="exit-on-suspend"            value="false" />          <!-- ios: if set to true, app will terminate when home button is pressed -->
    <preference name="show-splash-screen-spinner" value="true" />           <!-- ios: if set to false, the spinner won't appear on the splash screen during app loading -->
    <preference name="auto-hide-splash-screen"    value="true" />           <!-- ios: if set to false, the splash screen must be hidden using a JavaScript API -->
    <preference name="disable-cursor"             value="false" />          <!-- blackberry: prevents a mouse-icon/cursor from being displayed on the app -->
    <preference name="android-minSdkVersion"      value="7" />              <!-- android: MIN SDK version supported on the target device. MAX version is blank by default. -->
    <preference name="android-installLocation"    value="auto" />           <!-- android: app install location. 'auto' will choose. 'internalOnly' is device memory. 'preferExternal' is SDCard. -->

    <!-- Plugins can also be added here. -->
    <!--
        <gap:plugin name="Example" />
        A list of available plugins are available at https://build.phonegap.com/docs/plugins
    -->

    <gap:plugin name="com.pushwoosh.plugins.pushwoosh" version="3.0.2" />
    <gap:plugin name="com.phonegap.plugin.statusbar" />
    <preference name="StatusBarOverlaysWebView" value="true" />
    <preference name="StatusBarBackgroundColor" value="#1d1d1d" />

    <!-- Define app icon for each platform. -->
    <icon src="icon.png" />
    <icon src="res/icon/android/icon-36-ldpi.png"   gap:platform="android"    gap:density="ldpi" />
    <icon src="res/icon/android/icon-48-mdpi.png"   gap:platform="android"    gap:density="mdpi" />
    <icon src="res/icon/android/icon-72-hdpi.png"   gap:platform="android"    gap:density="hdpi" />
    <icon src="res/icon/android/icon-96-xhdpi.png"  gap:platform="android"    gap:density="xhdpi" />
    <icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-57.png"            gap:platform="ios"        width="57" height="57" />
    <icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-72.png"            gap:platform="ios"        width="72" height="72" />
    <icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-57-2x.png"         gap:platform="ios"        width="114" height="114" />
    <icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-72-2x.png"         gap:platform="ios"        width="144" height="144" />

    <!-- Define app splash screen for each platform. -->
    <gap:splash src="res/screen/android/screen-ldpi-portrait.png"  gap:platform="android" gap:density="ldpi" />
    <gap:splash src="res/screen/android/screen-mdpi-portrait.png"  gap:platform="android" gap:density="mdpi" />
    <gap:splash src="res/screen/android/screen-hdpi-portrait.png"  gap:platform="android" gap:density="hdpi" />
    <gap:splash src="res/screen/android/screen-xhdpi-portrait.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="xhdpi" />
    <gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-portrait.png"    gap:platform="ios"     width="320" height="480" />
    <gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-portrait-2x.png" gap:platform="ios"     width="640" height="960" />
    <gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-landscape.png" gap:platform="ios"     width="480" height="320" />
    <gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-landscape-2x.png" gap:platform="ios"     width="960" height="640" />
        <gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-portrait-568h-2x.png" gap:platform="ios"     width="640" height="1136" />
    <gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/screen-ipad-portrait.png"      gap:platform="ios"     width="768" height="1024" />
    <gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/screen-ipad-landscape.png"     gap:platform="ios"     width="1024" height="768" />
    <gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/screen-ipad-landscape-2x.png"     gap:platform="ios"     width="2008" height="1536" />
    <gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/screen-ipad-portrait-2x.png"     gap:platform="ios"     width="1536" height="2008" />

    <!--
        Define access to external domains.

        <access />            - a blank access tag denies access to all external resources.
        <access origin="*" /> - a wildcard access tag allows access to all external resource.

        Otherwise, you can specify specific domains:
    -->
    <access origin="*"/> <!-- allow local pages -->
      <access origin="https://cp.pushwoosh.com"/>
    <!--
        <access origin="http://phonegap.com" />                    - allow any secure requests to http://phonegap.com/
        <access origin="http://phonegap.com" subdomains="true" />  - same as above, but including subdomains, such as http://build.phonegap.com/
        <access origin="http://phonegap.com" browserOnly="true" /> - only allows http://phonegap.com to be opened by the child browser.
    -->

</widget>
```

when I add

```
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device" version="0.2.8" />
```

I get the error in the image below, I am using the **pooshwoosh** plug-in too. When I remove the **cordova** plug-in, I cant send **pooshwoosh** to android so I need it. Any idea?

THE ANDROID CODE is :

```
function registerPushwooshAndroid() {

    var pushNotification = window.plugins.pushNotification;

    //push notifications handler
    document.addEventListener('push-notification', function(event) {
                var title = event.notification.title;
                var userData = event.notification.userdata;
                var msg = event.notification.message;

                //dump custom data to the console if it exists
                if(typeof(userData) != "undefined") {
                    console.warn('user data: ' + JSON.stringify(userData));
                }

                //and show alert
                navigator.notification.alert(title);
                navigator.notification.alert(msg);

                //stopping geopushes
                pushNotification.stopGeoPushes();
              });

    //projectid: "GOOGLE_PROJECT_ID", appid : "PUSHWOOSH_APP_ID"
    pushNotification.registerDevice({ projectid: "------", appid : "-----" },
                                    function(token) {
                                        alert(token);
                                        //callback when pushwoosh is ready
                                        onPushwooshAndroidInitialized(token);
                                    },
                                    function(status) {
                                        alert("failed to register: " +  status);
                                        console.warn(JSON.stringify(['failed to register ', status]));
                                    });
 }
```

i think is somthing with verification ID ...

[image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fsdav.jpg)

Comment: Please show the android code.This is basically Android device token id in alert.

Comment: can you have a look on the answer ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `alert(token);` from the below method :

```
pushNotification.registerDevice({ projectid: "------", appid : "-----" },
                                function(token) {
                                    alert(token);
                                    //callback when pushwoosh is ready
                                    onPushwooshAndroidInitialized(token);
                                },
                                function(status) {
                                    alert("failed to register: " +  status);
                                    console.warn(JSON.stringify(['failed to register ', status]));
                                });
```

Comment: Yes that was the trick :) , thank you , please can you help me with another thing , when i send the notification , on android it shows only the logo and the title buth not the Message . i have added the alert (msg) like in code but not resolved the issue

Comment: Just add "navigator.notification.alert(userData );" below "navigator.notification.alert(msg);" in your code.

Comment: Are you getting message from server ? Check the valus of "msg" in var msg = event.notification.message;

Comment: i get the notification , i was reading another queston here and i found that , i dont know what to do ...

Comment: You can check value of msg by adding alert(msg)

Comment: where to add it ? below the navigator.notification.alert(title);

Comment: Below var msg = event.notification.message;

Comment: Then from your server side you are getting null value for message.Your code is fine.

Comment: and the other thing is that is working on IOS but not in android . in android when i press the notification alert the app doesnt start too...